# adding views to android layout on button click

Tags: android, dynamic, view

i want to dynamically add views (textview or EditText) to my layout as per user instructions.
i am developing this just to figure out things and learn how they work.
my XML file is as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="email1"
        />
        <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edit1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="enter mail "
        />

     </LinearLayout>    

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/phones"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="phone number"
        />
        <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edit2" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="enter phone "
        />

</LinearLayout>   

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myButtons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add mail"
        android:onClick="addmail"
                    />
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add phone"

                    />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

now here , i have two buttons. when the user clicks on addmail i want an edittext to be added to my layout (below my first email EditText in LinearLayout with id "email".
i have set android:onClick to addmail for the button 
and my addmail function is as follows:

```
public void addmail(){
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((LayoutParams. WRAP_CONTENT)   ,    (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    EditText edittv = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    edittv.setLayoutParams(lp);

    LinearLayout ll1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.email);

    ll1.addView(edittv);



}
```

but the code is not working . what modifications are required? where am i going wrong.
Are my concepts at fault?
thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Application Context` here: `EditText edittv = new EditText(getApplicationContext());`, just use specific `Activity Context` and it will solve your problem. I hope so :D!